# Checking if div element exists then return the innertext value of that div

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've searched through the site and while there's a lot of similar questions being asked, the responses while have helped somewhat I'm still running into an issue and can't quite figure it out.

I am trying to two things:

1. check if a div exists on the page
2. if it does exist get the inner text value then split that value to get the 3rd element within it to output to a new variable (which will be called elsewhere)

Here's the HTML div of the page & the JavaScript function:

```js
function listSizer() {
  var ListSizeYes = document.getElementById('divMsgPage');
  if (typeof(ListSizeYes) != 'undefined' || ListSizeYes != null) {
    return document.getElementById('divMsgPage').innerText.split(' ')[2];
  }
  var ListSizeNo = document.getElementById('divMsgPage');
  if (typeof(ListSizeNo) == 'undefined' || ListSizeNo == null) {
    console.log('no list size on page')
  }
}
var listSizeOutput = listSizer()
console.log(listSizeOutput)
```

```html
<div id="divMsgPage" class="l txtr pdt4 displayi fntsi mgr16">
  1 - 40 of 71<span id="hideResultsMob" class="fntsi mgl4">Results</span>
</div>
```

The issue I'm running into is when this element doesn't exist on the page in the console I'm getting the error " Cannot read property 'innerText' of null". I would expect on a page when that div doesn't exist for the function to go into the 2nd variable and not try to return the innerText but return in the console that 'no list size on page exists'.

If I change the logic from or i.e || in the if statement to && the error goes away but there's no output to the console when the div doesn't exist.

I'm relatively new to JS so I'm sure I've overlooked something simple.

Also, it does have to be pure JS and not jQuery due to other restrictions.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have ListSizeYes AND ListSizeYes   point at the same `document.getElementById('divMsgPage');`

Answer (score 0):

The first conditional is passing because `typeof(ListSizeYes) != 'undefined'` is `true`.

When `document.getElementById` finds no element, it returns `null` instead of `undefined`. And `typeof(null)` is not `undefined`, it's `object`.

You can fix your code changing it a little bit:

```js
function listSizer() {
  var div = document.getElementById('divMsgPage');
  if (div != null) {
    return div.innerText.split(' ')[2]; //careful here because you might get `undefined` if there are not 2 spaces in the string.
  }
  else{
    console.log('no list size on page');
    return null;
  }
}
var listSizeOutput = listSizer()
console.log(listSizeOutput)
```

```html
<div id="divMsgPage" class="l txtr pdt4 displayi fntsi mgr16">
  1 - 40 of 71<span id="hideResultsMob" class="fntsi mgl4">Results</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phiter for the explanation!! The modifications you made work and the explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified to this test for a falsy result since your tests are incorrect (null is not undefined):

```js
function listSizer(id) {
  var ListSizeYes = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ListSizeYes) {
    return ListSizeYes.innerText.split(' ')[2]; // assuming there is such a text 
  }
  console.log('no list size with id "'+id+'" on page');
  return null;
}
var listSizeOutput = listSizer("divMsgPage")
console.log(listSizeOutput)

listSizeOutput = listSizer("divMsgPageX")
console.log(listSizeOutput)
```

```html
<div id="divMsgPage" class="l txtr pdt4 displayi fntsi mgr16">
  1 - 40 of 71<span id="hideResultsMob" class="fntsi mgl4">Results</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - your modifications work but I'm not clear on on the 2nd listSizeOutput you added "listSizeOutput = listSizer("divMsgPageX")".  This is returning in both situations, when the div exists and when it doesn't, why is that?

Comment: I used the second to show the message when the div did not exist. There is no divMsgPageX on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refactor your code like this.

```
function listSizer() {
    var ListSizeYes = document.getElementById('divMsgPage');
    if (ListSizeYes) 
        return document.getElementById('divMsgPage').innerText.split(' ')[2];
    else
        console.log('no list size on page')
}

var listSizeOutput = listSizer()
console.log(listSizeOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code , i tried removing content and remove  div and works

```js
function listSizer() {
  var div = document.getElementById('divMsgPage');
  if ( div && div.innerText.split(' ')[2]!==undefined ) {
    console.log( div.innerText.split(' ')[2]); //careful here because you might get `undefined` if there are not 2 spaces in the string.
  }
  else{
    console.log('no list size on page')
  }
}
var listSizeOutput = listSizer()
```

```html
<div id="divMsgPage" class="l txtr pdt4 displayi fntsi mgr16">
1 - 40 of 71<span id="hideResultsMob" class="fntsi mgl4">Results</span>
</div>
```